# How do I set up nginx to serve data from a port?

Tags: nginx, virtual-directory

I have nginx serving a page on port 80.

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name .example.com;
root       /var/www/docs;
index      index.html;
}
```

I also have a service running a server on port 9000. How do I set up a virtual directory in nginx (such as /service) to serve whatever is on port 9000? I am unable to open other ports, so I would like to serve this through some kind of virtual directory on port 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with [that](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) (but you definetly will need more directives to make your server normally answering on this subdirectory):

```
location /something {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: There's a tutorial expanding upon this method here: https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0. One important point to note from it is that for /something you would need a rewrite rule to re-map from /something to /.